# Unity Assets folder is empty after opening package from the asset store

Tags: unity

I downloaded the following Survival Shooter Tutorial from the Asset Store :

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/40756

I was prompted to open it in Unity so I did and began following this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lP6epjupJs

I am only 2 minutes into the first video and am stuck. In the tutorial there are lots of folders in the assets folder. I took a screenshot of what my screen looks like to show that it is empty.

[image: Empty Unity project]

Comment: You have to add the package to your project. You're conflating a download with an import.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to have Unity open FIRST then download the package from the Asset store INSIDE Unity

Comment: Or you can double-click on a package file you downloaded externally to launch Unity and import it into your current project. Or from within Unity right click in your project browser and select Import Package...